# Pythagorean-like theorem for products of random matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Define "normalized Frobenius norm" $\rho$ as follows

$$\rho(M)=\frac{\|MM^T\|_F}{\operatorname{Tr}(MM^T)}$$

For $n\times n$ random matrices $A,B$ with IID random entries, the following appears to be true as $n\to \infty$. Why?

$$n \rho(AB)^2+1=n \rho(A)^2+n \rho(B)^2$$

For instance, let $n=4000$, $A$ with standard normal entries, $B$ with uniform(-1,1):
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n \rho (A)^2 & 2.00029 \\
 n \rho (B)^2 & 2.00044 \\
 n \rho (AB)^2+1 & 4.00185 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-additivity-of-norms.nb)

Comment: Since the square of the Frobenius norm is the sum of squares of elements, I'm not too surprised that a Pythagorean-like relationship is appearing. But looking at the expressions, I can't think of how the product of two matrices is translating into a sum expression

Comment: @TonyMathew another intriguing thing is that $n \rho(A)^2$ seems to be the same regardless of distribution of entries, if it's centered at zero. IE, uniform(-10,10), normal, difference of exponentials, all produce 2.

Comment: This seems to be related to the [Marchenko-Pastur distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution), which is the limiting law of the empirical eigenvalue distribution of $(MM^T)/n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: OK you are right, multiplying such matrices their second moments add, eq 3.54 of [thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06128.pdf)